# FFmpegで音源ファイルを生成した時の冒頭0.2秒の空白を無くしたい

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Deezerが提供している [Spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) をPythonで利用するにあたって，自分のパソコンではメモリが足りなかったため，[Pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) を用いて元ファイルを1分毎に分割することにしました。私がしたかったことは，これら分割したファイルをSpleeterで処理した後，再び結合してフル尺にすることでした。

しかし，分割したファイルはそれぞれの冒頭に揃って0.2秒の無音が含まれていたため，再び結合すると楽曲が途切れることが分かりました。
後から0.2秒消去すればいいだけなのですが，それではどうもすっきりしないのでPydubの中身を見てみると，FFmpegのコマンドを実行しているらしかったので，手に負えないと思い質問した次第です。

質問としては，後から0.2秒消去するしかないのか，そうでなければどんな方法があるのか，になります。
質問に過不足あれば申し訳ないです。ご教示お願いします。

コードは以下で全部です。一応意図を追記しておきましたが，正確性に欠けるかもしれません。

```py
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

input_file = "./music"

for input_name in os.listdir(input_file):
#music内の全楽曲に対して繰り返す
    input_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(f'./music/{input_name}')
    #特定の1楽曲をinput_audioに入れる
    input_length = input_audio.duration_seconds
    #再生時間を代入
    for i in range(int(input_length // 60 + 1)):
    #分数+1回繰り返す
        sliced = input_audio[i * 60*1000: (i+1) * 60*1000]
        #1分だけslicedにコピー
        sliced.export(f"./output/sliced/{i}{input_name}")
        #番号付きでslicedをエクスポート
```

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかもしれません。[Wav to mp3 conversion #100](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/100)

Comment: ありがとうございます！